# Use file() in remote-exec

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I successfully created an Azure Ubuntu VM in Terraform that runs a remote-exec provisioner after the creation has been completed. Within this remote-exec block I create user accounts that can be accessed via SSH. Since I have the public keys, I also want to add each public key to their respective authorized_keys file. My approach is this:

```
"sudo adduser --quiet --disabled-password --shell /bin/bash --home /home/username--gecos \"Firstname Lastname\" username", 
"sudo mkdir ~/../username/.ssh",
"sudo chmod 700 ~/../username/.ssh/",
"sudo touch ~/../username/.ssh/authorized_keys",
"sudo echo ${file("userKeys/username.pub")} > ~/../username/.ssh/authorized_keys",
"sudo chmod 600 ~/../username/.ssh/authorized_keys",
"sudo chown -R username.username ~/../username/"
```

Unfortunately, this causes Terraform to crash after applying, probably due to the double quotes within file. So I also tried

```
"echo ${file("userKeys/username.pub")}"
```

which works perfectly fine.

At this point I don't really know how to solve this problem. Maybe using file() within remote-exec is the wrong approach anyway?

Comment: Where is the file userKeys/username.pub? Is it in your remote Azure VM or local machine? Do you mean you have public keys on the local machine?

Comment: In this case, yes, I have that public key on the same local machine that executes the terraform script. userKeys is just a subfolder within this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can use the Provisioner [Connection](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/connection.html) to create an SSH connection and use Provisioner [File](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/file.html) to copy the local file to the remote machine.

Here is a working sample on my side with the following configuration environment.

```
Terraform v0.15.0
on windows_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.57.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v3.1.0
```

For example,

```
resource "null_resource" "example_provisioner" {

  triggers = {
    public_ip = azurerm_public_ip.example.ip_address
  }

  connection {
    type  = "ssh"
    host  = azurerm_public_ip.example.ip_address
    user  = "testadmin"
    private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
    # password = "${var.root_password}"
    }

  provisioner "file" {
    source  = "test.pub"  # local public key
    destination  = "/tmp/test.pub"  # will copy to remote VM as /tmp/test.pub
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
"sudo adduser --quiet --disabled-password --shell /bin/bash --home /home/username --gecos \"Firstname Lastname\" username", 
"sudo mkdir ~/../username/.ssh",
"sudo chmod 700 ~/../username/.ssh/",
"sudo touch ~/../username/.ssh/authorized_keys",
"sudo cp /tmp/test.pub ~/../username/.ssh/authorized_keys",
"sudo chmod 600 ~/../username/.ssh/authorized_keys",
"sudo chown -R username.username ~/../username/"

    ]
  }

}
```

[image]